# SQL query to prepend prefix to existing value in a field

Tags: mysql, sql, joomla, phpmyadmin

I have searched and searched for an answer to this, and I think this must be child's play for anyone who KNOWS SQL (which is not me).

I want to insert a prefix to the values in a field of a table in my DB.

More specifically, I have a table jos_content in which I have a field 'title' (which contains the titles of the content items of my joomla site).

All the values in this field 'title' are names of individuals. Now all I want to do is add a prefix 'Mr.' to all the values of this field.

I can do this from phpmyadmin by clicking the edit pencil icon and simply adding Mr. in front of all the values but I have about 750 rows and an SQL command which can insert a prefix of 'Mr.' in front of all values of this field will be a great help.

I have read about the 'UPDATE' commands but that REPLACES the value with what you provide. But I want to let the values remain and add a prefix before them.

Please can anyone help me achieve this with a SQL command ?

Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 100):

You have no other conditions like update this in all rows then you can try

```
UPDATE jos_content SET title = CONCAT('Mr. ', title)
```

if you want to update conditionally that means particular row needs to update
the you can use

```
 UPDATE jos_content SET title = CONCAT('Mr. ', title)  where fiedl_name ='condition'

eg: UPDATE jos_content SET title = CONCAT('Mr. ', title)  where id = '1'
```

this will update only one row which contain id=1.

any way before doing this should keep a backup

Comment: UPDATE `installations` ins SET ins.`meter_msn` = CONCAT(ins.`meter_msn`,'U') WHERE ins.`meter_msn` IN ('20373121578800',
'20373153162100',
'20373150840900',
'20373150580101',
'20373150577700',
'20373150577200',
'20373311012300',
'20373150574901')

It's not working for me

Comment: I want to add `U` in front of each number. the number is in string format

Comment: @MrFaisal `CONCAT('U ', ins.meter_msn)` is right for add in the front.

Answer (score 6):

`UPDATE jos_content SET title = CONCAT('Mr. ', title) WHERE 1`

Before testing the query do make a database backup.

Answer (score 5):

```
update tablename set title = 'Mr. ' || title where ....
```

Answer (score 1):

just do it like this

If, for example, I want to add +symbol before the countrycode:

```
UPDATE [masters].[country] SET Countrycode = '+' +Countrycode
```